# Sort and Show push notification in list

Tags: android, sorting, push-notification, android-sqlite

I am implementing the push notification in android and following the process that in receiver of notification making the notification entry in database with current date and time along with it.

Now i want to show the List of all notification but in **SORTED** manner of dates it has been received,  like last notification should be shown at first in list.

i am trying to sort but **SQLITE** does not support Date type rather i saved it as String in dd-mm-yyyy format.

How can i sort the Notification on the bases of dates? please help

Comment: store your date in form of yyyy-MM-dd and then execute your query it will work for you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have changed the date format to yyyy-MM-dd and surprisingly it works.

Now my sort query will filter the dates on the basis of firstly for years, then  months, and then dates.

Answer (score 0):

If you store the date in the right format (always use 2 digit hour/minute/second/day/month, 4 digit year, in order from largest time unit to smallest) you can just sort by sorting the strings.

Comment: Largest to smallest surely? Seconds will wrap every minute.